# Error: unexpected string constant

Tags: r, machine-learning, stocks

I'm getting this error:

`Error: unexpected string constant in "colnames(dji)[dm[2]] [1] "..11""`

when running this command:

`colnames(dji)[dm[2]] [1] "..11"`

Basically, the exact same thing is done [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/using-logistic-regression-predict-market-direction-algorithmic-trading/), it has all the coding.

But with Amazon stock. Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you expect `".. 11"` to do? To R, this is a misplaced string it cannot understand.

Comment: That packtpub article is poorly formatted (it's just wrong!). There should be a newline before the `[1]`, indicating that `[1] "..11"` is *output from R*, not part of intended input command. Those three lines: show the column name before the change, then makes the change, then shows the changed column name (again, the `[1] "Direction"` should be on its own line).

Answer (score 1):

You mistook output like

```
[1] "..11"
```

for part of the command. Leave it out.